# How to load resource bundle in a servlet (JSF)

Tags: jsf, servlets, resourcebundle

I am using JSF and have made a custom servlet for loading images dynamically.

I want this servlet to pick up my image folder location i.e. "F:\photos\images\" from the resource bundle. How do I access my resource bundle defined in my faces-config? 
I do not want to hard code this value in the servlet :/

Comment: This kind of configuration settings should not go in a resource bundle file (which is intended for localization), but in a normal properties file which you load by `java.util.Properties`.

Comment: I agree BalusC, that's the other point I had, resources are for localization but both are loaded at applicationScope. Actually a matter of the convention that is followed. Thanks! will change it though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a resource bundle defined like this:

```xml
<resource-bundle>
   <base-name>/resources/bundle</base-name>
   <var>bundle</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

In Java you can access this property file like this:

```java
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
...
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/resources/bundle");
String val = config.getString(key);
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. That'll do the trick...but just curious...is it ok to load the resourceBundle again as above? I mean they are applicationScoped and already loaded at server startup right?

Comment: @AKSHAT: I would load it in an application scoped bean and inject it then into all places where it is needed.

Comment: Makes sense. Keeps it simple. Thanks!